# Cannot assign a value of type CGFloat to a value of type CGFloat

Tags: swift, casting, calayer

I'm getting an error when trying to set the zPosition of a `CAShapeLayer`. Here's the code:

```
self.view.layer.sublayers[l].zPosition = CGFloat(1)
```

For some reason I'm getting this error: `Cannot assign a value of type CGFloat to a value of type CGFloat!`. For some reason, the error is with the optional. I've seen other examples online done without any casting (`zPosition = 1`), so I don't know what the issue is here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `sublayers` property of a `CALayer` is defined as `[AnyObject]!`.  When you subscript as `...sublayers[l]` you are getting an `AnyObject` which, to be sure, does not have a settable property of `zPosition`.  You need to downcast the returned `AnyObject` to a `CALayer` with, for example

```
if let layer = self.view.layer.sublayers[l] as? CALayer {
  layer.zPosition = CGFloat(1)
}
```

Also, you don't need to unwrap `sublayers` (before subscripting) because it is declared with `!` and is thus implicitly, automatically unwrapped.

Finally, the error message you quoted appears to be mis-copied as it is nonsensical.

Comment: Whoops, mis-copied. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

sublayers is defined as an Optional array of AnyObject's. Therefore you have to unwrap sublayers. The following should work:

```
self.view.sublayers![l].zPosition = CGFloat(1)
```

Comment: yes.. you are right.. sorry for that one. @GoZoner got it right =)

Comment: No worries! Thanks for taking the time to answer.